# Stopping calling an API on every ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular Front-end for a web based application. There are several sub-page drill downs (different angular components) that all make the same API call in the ngOnInit() method. This constant number of calls is causing a slow down when we start getting a high level of users using the application. I am looking for a means to save this data so I can call it across the pages that way the number of API calls is reduced.

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.api.validInputParams()) {
        this.api.getLiveData().subscribe((response) => {
            //do page specific function and filtering

        }, (error) => {
            // Any error should be caught in the HttpInterceptor
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it kind of depends... does this data ever NEED to be updated? when? how?

Comment: Not exactly sure if I understood the question completely. Maybe one option is to save the data in Session Storage and just read it from there? Or if its child components, you can use Input/Output to pass the data. Maybe use rxjs Subject to pass the data to components on same level etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can call the api only once into the top level component and communicate with sub pages with @Input(), 1 way data binding.
Into the top level component :

top-component.ts (call the api and save it into a variable)

```
public response;

ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getData().subscribe(response => this.response = response);
```

top-component.html (send it to the sub-page)

```
<app-children [response]="response"></app-children>
```

sub-page (reference to the response)

```
@Input() response;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass them down with 2-Way-DataBinding
If that's not possible the easiest solution would be to save it
in the localStorage with `localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(yourData);`
and to read it out you can use `yourData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));`

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be updated, just save it in your service and instead of making the http call, return what's already saved. If it needs to be updated, you could also save the last updated time and if its too big of a difference, you make the call.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation for component interaction options: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
I prefer for myself to use service in cases like yours (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

You can have BehaviorSubject in your service and you can subscribe to it in your components.